# Calling Javascript Function in C# not working properly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I wanna call a javascript function in c sharp code.
i wanna hide the specific Li tag whose id is c sharp variable"li_name".
For this  i am calling a javascript function.

Cs Code:

```
  li_name = DSRolePermission.Tables[0].Rows[k]["MENUNAME"].ToString();
  StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

  script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

  script.Append("li_visibility('" + li_name + "')");

  script.Append("</script>");

  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(object), "JavaScriptBlock", script.ToString());
```

JS code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           function li_visibility('<%=li_name %>') {
document.getElementById('<%=li_name %>').style.display = 'hidden';

      }      
</script>
```

But this code is not working properly.

Comment: You are passing "li_name" in server inline side script to the li_visibility function in js.Then why are you again dynamically passing on the client end javscript function "li_visibility('<%=li_name %>')" like this?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your js-code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function li_visibility(id) {
       document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';    
   }      
</script>
```

I you want to use hidden value, use the visibility property;

```
element.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //'visible' to show;
```

Note:
   When using **visibility:hidden**, the space occupied by the element is still present.
   **display:none**, will hide both the element and the occupied space.

Comment: this would work just pass the li_name in javascript function from server side  like Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(object), "JavaScriptBlock","li_visibility("+li_name+")");

Comment: this is also not working..:-(Is it necessary to change code of C sharp function.

Comment: also ensure that if your server event causing partial load of page then the case may be different. check for error's in firebug console

Comment: a little typo in the code in my comment please try this 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(object), "JavaScriptBlock","<script>li_visibility("+li_name+")</script>");

Comment: @pallavisahane if still not working please explain exactly what's wrong - you get error? Also, see my answer for something else you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

By having the same key, only the first call will be executed and the rest ignored silently.

Assuming you have this code in a loop, add the element ID to the JS key:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(this), "JavaScriptBlock_" + li_name, script.ToString());
```

Also changed the type, it's better practice to pass the type of the calling page/control.

Comment: +1 for this extra information "Also changed the type, it's better practice to pass the type of the calling page/control."

Answer (score 0):

Why you add a c# var inside the JS ? just update it to : 
`<script type="text/javascript">
function li_visibility(x) { 
document.getElementById(x).style.display = 'hidden';
}</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function li_visibility('<%=li_name %>') 
    {
        document.getElementById('<%=li_name.ClientID %>').style.display = 'hidden';
    }      
</script>
```

This may help